# How to make Retroarch start on Ubuntu server 14.04 boot

Tags: 14.04, boot

I have these old AMD based systems that I want to make them into retro gaming consoles. One option was Lakka, but it doesn't work on AMD systems.

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 server (I think it uses less resources than desktop with GUI), installed Retroarch and when I try to launch it (typing in the console retroarch) it works like it should. However I don't want the kids to do it. I would like it to run automatically. I tried adding it to `/etc/rc.local/` but that doesn't work. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if you tried this but you can try making a `.conf` file containing the following lines

```
start on startup
task
exec /path/to/command
```

and save this `.conf` in `/etc/init`

Comment: First of all thank you for the help but that didnt work either... or i dont know how to use it. I even made ubuntu to auto login on boot hoping that would work but it didnt.... i created .conf file in /etc/init with: start on startup task exec retroarch, that didnt work then i made retroarch.sh file and at the exec line i pointed to the retroarch.sh, retroarch.sh just had the line retroarch in it. I am probably doing something wrong arent i ?

Comment: Never mind... thanks again, i figured it out, i was doing it wrong. It works :) There is one thing tho... some assets and graphics dont load if it autostarts.. is there a way to add like a sleep command so that .conf runs once ubuntu is fully loaded or after 20 sec ?

Comment: @xPalis yes there is one but i am not sure it will work properly but if you want to try it out it is the following command/line `sleep (number how long you want the delay in seconds) && (file name)` the last two things is what i am doubting about (meaning the `&& (file name)`). this line should be the first line and perhaps the `&& (file name)` is not needed

Comment: @xPalis any updates?

Comment: i tried sleep command before you commented and that didnt work well... i ended up creating .config file in /etc/init/, inside i used start on started tty1 task exec "location to my sh file" and everything works as it should now, thanks for the help :)

Comment: @xPalis your welcome and just a tip, if something is answer do mark it or add the solution you found to the question as people will be looking around for the solution to a problem that seems similar to what you had and will try what they can find if a solution is provided and thye will be gald they found it in our question/post/how ever you want to call it